# Get Topmost thread in outlook email C#.net

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

Is it possible to get only the topmost thread of an outlook email?

Say the email looks like this...

> **Hi John,
>
>                   Yes we can get that!! I hope.. 
>
> Regards, 
>   
>
> signature_here**
>   
>   
>   From: John Doe 
> Sent: Wednesday, November 4, 2015 6:02 AM 
>   
> To:
>   to@email.com 
>   
> Cc: CC@email.com 
>   
> Subject: How to get this? 
>   
> Hi Bob,
>   
>   something something

I only need to get the bolded text. Is that possible? My code in getting an email:

```
        OutLook.Application oApp;
        OutLook._NameSpace oNS;
        OutLook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
        OutLook._Explorer oExp;
    try
    {
        oApp = new OutLook.Application();
        oNS = (OutLook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        oExp = oFolder.GetExplorer(false);
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

        foreach (OutLook.MailItem mail in oFolder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true"))
        {
            var subject = mail.Subject;
            var body = mail.Body; //But I only need the bolded text and not the entire thread...
            var x = mail.HTMLBody;
            var y = mail.RTFBody;
            var userName = string.Empty;
            var attachment = mail.Attachments;
            OutLook.ExchangeUser exUser = mail.Sender.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exUser != null)
            {
                userName = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                userName = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
            }
            mail.UnRead = false;
            mail.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        oApp = null;
        oNS = null;
        oFolder = null;
        oExp = null;
    }
```

Comment: You can try and look for clues that the next message has started, like the header information or a horizontal rule, but I don't believe there is an API for this because most mail clients just copy the body of the original message to a reply and add information at the top, there is no universal message delimiter that identifies the individual messages in the body, its entirely dependent on the client that creates the message.

Comment: Hi @RonBeyer, I see... On my research, I found out and thought that Conversation class was the key but then it wasn't... I was hoping that the email thread is in an array or something... So I guess not. I was also eyeing for that horizontal line but its only present when the email is sent AsHTML but AsPlainText, that line is replaced as ----Original Text---- Or something...